# Synchronous observable angular

Tags: angular, observable, synchronous

I use a API in order to get information. However, sometimes I get all the information, sometimes I get just some and sometimes they are not in the good order.

```ts
getData(start: string, fin: string) {
  this.tab = [];
  var index = parseInt(start);
  this.service.getInfos(start, fin).subscribe(data => {
    data.results.forEach((element, i) => {
      var name;
      var type;
      var description;
      name = element.name;
      this.service.getInfo((index + 1).toString()).subscribe(datatype => {
        if (datatype.types.length > 1) {
          type = datatype.types[1].type.name;
        } else {
          type = datatype.types[0].type.name;
        }
      });
      this.service.getDescription((index + 1).toString()).subscribe(datades => {
        datades.flavor_text_entries.forEach(el => {
          if (el.language.name.toString() == 'en') {
            description = el.flavor_text;
          }
        });
        var value = new data(this.tab.length + 1, name, info, description);
        this.tab.push(poke);
      });
      index++;
    });
  });
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help. 
I use Observable to get result of my http request

Comment: There isn't a clear question here. Can you explain a bit more in details what you want to achieve and what you tried so far?

Comment: You could sort the data once the last `this.service.getDescription` is called, assuming that's this is what you wanted.

Comment: I would suggest reading [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-rxjs-tutorial/) and other tutorials on asynchronous programming to get a better understanding of how it works and how it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get familiar with services in angular to get the data and using promises instead of subscription cause they laod the data fully and in promises you get all the data at once not as a fluctuation of data that the subscribe is doing. Subscription is ment only to notify if there are some changes in the variable or component. Promises gets called when the whole is loaded.